# How to retrieve all keys of Redis set after adding using sadd operation

Tags: redis

I am using RedisCluster to access information. Here is my code:

```
package kafka;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
import redis.clients.jedis.JedisCluster;
import redis.clients.jedis.ScanParams;
import redis.clients.jedis.ScanResult;

public class RedisExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JedisCluster connection = JedisConnection.getInstance().getconnection();
    connection.sadd("mykeys_key1", "attr1:string");
    connection.sadd("mykeys_key1", "attr2:string");
    connection.sadd("mykeys_key2", "attr1:string");
    connection.sadd("mykeys_key2", "attr2:string");
    connection.sadd("mykeys_key3", "attr1:string");
    connection.sadd("mykeys_key3", "attr2:string");
    System.out.println(connection.smembers("mykeys_key1"));

}

}
```

Output: `[attr2:string, attr1:string]`

I want to retrieve all keys which matches the pattern `**mykeys_***`.

I am looking for something similar to this:

`connection.smembers("mykeys_*") ---` this should give me all keys, i.e., `mykeys_key3, mykeys_key2, mykeys_key1`.

Based on these keys, I will make another call to `Redis connection.smember("mykeys_key3")` to get individual set.

**hkeys** works on hash so not useful for this scenarios. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`KEYS mykeys_*` will return the keys that match that pattern.

Take heed of the warning on the [doc page for KEYS](https://redis.io/commands/keys):

> Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in
>   production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance
>   when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended
>   for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace
>   layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're
>   looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider
>   using SCAN or sets.

Comment: So why not recommend using `SCAN` in the first place?

Comment: TheDude -  Could you please help me with Java API for this. I am using JedisCluster client and couldn't find one. It provides **hkeys** which will not work with my set as it is not hash based. 

@Itamar Haber  Yes it is recommended one. I am looking around that. Thanks!

Comment: @tryingSpark the Jedis client has that command https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/main/java/redis/clients/jedis/Client.java#L88

Comment: Yes. But I am using JEDISCLUSTER client which dont have that